# check user bandwidth

Tags: php, vb.net, bandwidth

how do i check the bandwidth (download speed and possible upload speed) of a user in vb.net or php that uses my app or visits my site resp?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you test it.  Check out [SpeedTest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) for an example.

You download a file, and then upload it and measure the times.

Most of the online speed testers use flash for this purpose, so the user doesn't have to worry about browsing for a file to upload.

Comment: Thanks, but am talking about doing it in php and vb.net

Comment: @Smith, Yes, and the method doesn't change.  In a VB.NET WinForms, download a file from your web server and measure the time it takes.  Then, POST it back and see how long it takes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92522/http-get-in-vb-net  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981354/how-to-post-a-file-via-http-post-in-vb-net  PHP comes into play when posting the file back, as something has to receive that data.

Comment: that would give me a static speed , where in real world, it varies by the second. sometimes up, sometimes down. how do i show this variation live?

Comment: @Smith, you check it over and over again, or continuously download and check the speed over the last second, or some interval.  Of course, by doing this you are sucking up a lot of user bandwidth, and I don't imagine this is what you're after.  What are you trying to do?