# HTTP Post To Self To Test Handler

Tags: asp.net, http, httpwebrequest, http-headers, handler

I am currently working with a generic handler in asp.net. I believe it is currently in a sort of "listening" state awaiting POSTs. I am expecting a POST with a filename Header, and once received the handler will deal with downloading the file. My handler code is below:

```
Sub ProcessRequest(Byval context as HttpContext) Implements IHttpHanlder.ProcessRequest

If context.Request.HttpMethod() = "POST" Then
Dim Reader as New StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream)
Dim contents as String = reader.ReadtoEnd()

Dim filename as String = context.Request.Headers(("filename"))
System.IO.File.Writealltext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("outputdirectory"), contents)
Else
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
context.Response.ContentType("Handler is alive")
End If

End Sub
```

I would like to replicate a post and see if it takes it in successfully. Would it be possible to generate and send this post from another program on my machine. I have attempted a few tutorials including this one

[SO - POST Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981354/how-to-post-a-file-via-http-post-in-vb-net)

I feel that I have gotten the closest using this code(from previous link)

```
Using wc as New System.Net.WebClient
wc.UploadFile("http://localhost:Port/local/of/handler", "C:\local\of\file.txt")
End Using
```

I am receiving a 500 error from the remote server. Would this be an issue with the handlers code? Or am I just not making the right type of POST?

When messing around with wc.Headers()/Darin's suggestion I still get a 500 error. The exception is below.

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.Net.Webclient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at System.Net.WebClient.WebClientWriteStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()
at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
at TestPOSTGETEXE.Form1.Button4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\blah\blah\..\..\..\
```

Comment: Your client code isn't even attempting to set the header that your handler code expects.

Comment: I will edit I have messed around with things such as wc.Headers.Add but cant seem to get it straight

Comment: "messing around" is not as helpful as actual code.

Comment: Using Darin Dimitrov's code, I didnt think I needed to post it as my own

Comment: I only saw your comment to his answer after commenting here. My bad :)

Comment: No worries I edited to to clarify I was "messing around" with Darin's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
    wc.Headers("filename") = "file.txt"
    Using writer = wc.OpenWrite("http://localhost:Port/local/of/handler")
        Dim file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\local\of\file.txt")
        writer.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: @harper89, what exception are you getting inside the handler when you debug it? There seems to be some problem when you try to write the file contents WriteAllText - are you sure that the path is correct and that the account has sufficient privileges to write to this folder? Also in your handler you don't seem to use the filename header, you use some `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("outputdirectory")` which looks more like a directory name, not a filename, so it could be the reason why your generic handler crashes. You should probably `Path.Combine` this value with the `filename` variable.

Comment: Was coming back to make an update but looks like you figured it out first. When debugging the handler it seems I can't get to any directory. Every location throws "UnauthorizedAccessException" Access to path "C:\dir\to\put\stuff" is denied

Comment: @harper89, so: `File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("outputdirectory"), filename), contents)`.

Comment: Thats perfect, thanks for the help, I left off the space after your "outputdirectoy ", I am assuming it was a typo :). Cheers