# Upload to my website from my VB.net application

Tags: php, vb.net, file-upload

I'm designing a site that I'll be uploading content to from my VB.net program.  I've also set up the stuff so you can upload content from one of the pages:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
        Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
```

Is there any way to upload using this same method, but with my VB.net program?  I'm using VB.net so all .net examples and solutions are acceptable :)

**EDIT:**

Here is a copy of what upload.php is:

```
<?php

        //Check that we have a file
        if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
          //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
          $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
          $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
          if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && 
            ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 350000)) {
            //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
              $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/uploads/'.$filename;
              //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
              if (!file_exists($newname)) {
                //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
                if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
                   echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
                } else {
                   echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!<br /><br /><a href='index.php'>Try Uploading Again</a>";
                }
              } else {
                 echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]." already exists!  That's our fault.  Please be patient while we fix it :)<br /><br /><a href='index.php'>Try Uploading Again</a>";
              }
          } else {
             echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload<br /><br /><a href='index.php'>Try Uploading Something Smaller</a>";
          }
        } else {
         echo "Error: No file uploaded";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: That's exactly what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981354/how-to-post-a-file-via-http-post-in-vb-net

Comment: @KonstantinPereyaslov I couldn't get any of those answers to work.  I've included some extra source code to see if that helps :)

Comment: You can mimic that HTML Upload functionality in VB.Net, simply google the WebClient class in the .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said in comments you need `System.Net.WebClient`. Your problems can be caused by not having proper headers

```
.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")
.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentLanguage, "en-gb")
```

Or by not handling cookies properly:
 [It Could Be Done!: WebClient: Handling Cookies](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html)