# Visual Basic - Upload file to PHP webpage

Tags: php, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to upload an image file to a PHP file on a web server.

On VB.NET ->

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(tempImageLocation, "website.com/upload.php")
```

tempImageLocation is a location on the harddrive where the image is located. The image **is** located on the harddrive where I specify it.

On PHP ->

```
$image = $_FILES['uploads']['name'];
```

I don't understand, because it is loading the page - but PHP can't find the file under 'uploads'

Answer (score 6):

Google brought me here while I was searching for the same question. Thanks people it gave me the idea, and with a little knowledge of PHP, I've achieved it. I know its an old question but still I'm going to share my code so it could help people in future..

VB:

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("e:\file1.jpg", "http://www.mysite.com/upl/upl.php")
```

PHP:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

and don't forget to give the upload folder the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Thanks so much! Although I don't need it anymore, I do appreciate you took the time to help answer this question.

Comment: I've been looking for this for a long time. Thanks for posting it, you never know who needs it.

Answer (score 2):

I know, is old.. but here is solution work to me:

```
    Private Sub HttpUploadFile(
ByVal uri As String,
ByVal filePath As String,
ByVal fileParameterName As String,
ByVal contentType As String)

    Dim myFile As New FileInfo(filePath)
    Dim sizeInBytes As Long = myFile.Length

    Dim boundary As String = "---------------------------" & DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")
    Dim newLine As String = System.Environment.NewLine
    Dim boundaryBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newLine & "--" & boundary & newLine)
    Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.KeepAlive = True
    'request.Credentials = Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Using requestStream As IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        Dim formDataTemplate As String = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""{0}""{1}{1}{2}"
        requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length)

        Dim headerTemplate As String = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""{0}""; filename=""{1}""{2}Content-Type: {3};"
        Dim header As String = String.Format(headerTemplate, fileParameterName, filePath, newLine, contentType)
        header = header & vbNewLine & "Content-Length: " & sizeInBytes.ToString & vbNewLine
        header = header & "Expect: 100-continue" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

        'MsgBox(header)
        Debug.Print(header)

        Dim headerBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header)
        requestStream.Write(headerBytes, 0, header.Length)

        Using fileStream As New IO.FileStream(filePath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
            Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
            Dim bytesRead As Int32 = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            Do While (bytesRead > 0)
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            Loop
        End Using
        Dim trailer As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newLine & "--" + boundary + "--" & newLine)
        requestStream.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length)
        requestStream.Close()
    End Using


    Dim response As Net.WebResponse = Nothing
    Try
        response = request.GetResponse()
        Using responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Using responseReader As New IO.StreamReader(responseStream)
                Dim responseText = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
                Debug.Print(responseText)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch exception As Net.WebException
        response = exception.Response
        If (response IsNot Nothing) Then
            Using reader As New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Dim responseText = reader.ReadToEnd()
                Diagnostics.Debug.Write(responseText)
            End Using
            response.Close()
        End If
    Finally
        request = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

Using:

```
HttpUploadFile("https://www.yousite.com/ws/upload.php?option1=sss&options2=12121", FULL_FILE_NAME_PATH_IN_YOUR_PC, "files", "multipart/form-data")
```

I copy somen code in a website i dont remember. 
I only put this 2 lines of code to work:

header = header & vbNewLine & "Content-Length: " & sizeInBytes.ToString & vbNewLine
header = header & vbNewLine & "Expect: 100-continue" & vbNewLine

hope help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete example for uploading file using **Visual Basic** and on Server Side **PHP (Rest API)** [**GitHub Link**](https://github.com/MuhammadUsman722/File-Uploading-using-VB-PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick and dirty tutorial for you: [PHP File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

'uploads' is just name attribute value of  element of a form:

`<input type="file" name="uploads" />`

or in other words, this is POST variable name that is accessed over $_FILES global.

Comment: Haha. Funny, but the reason it needs to be uploaded via Visual Basic is because my application is making the image and needs to upload - and it needs to seamlessly upload it. I don't want my users to have to find the image itself to upload it! :p

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the field name, you can save the uploaded file with this

```
$file = array_shift($_FILES);
move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], '/path/to/new/location/'.$file['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981894/288357) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10631355/288357) answers. PHP requires files uploaded with the POST method to use [certain headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) which are normally set by the browser when uploading from a web form but which can be set in VB with the [HttpWebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

As for the PHP side, you aren't going to be able to locate the file immediately after uploading with `$image = $_FILES['uploads']['name'];`. PHP stores uploads with a temporary filename accessible with the `$_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name']` variable, and using `move_uploaded_file()` is the standard way of shifting uploads from temporary storage into a permanent uploads directory. The [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) provides a good overview of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my sample server php file:

```
<?php
// write to a log file so you know it's working
$msg = $_POST['w'];
$logfile= 'data.txt';

$fp = fopen($logfile, "a");
fwrite($fp, $msg);
fclose($fp);

$file = array_shift($_FILES);
move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], '/MAMP/htdocs/test/'.$file['name']);

?>
```

Here's the code to call @Rodrigo's code:

```
HttpUploadFile("http://localhost/test/test.php?w=hello&options2=12121", "C:\temp\bahamas.mp3", "files", "multipart/form-data")
```