# WebApi Usage in .NET (Visual Basic) with FileUpload

Tags: .net, vb.net, rest, post, basic-authentication

I want to use a WebAPI, that requires BasicAuth to post a File, but I cant find any information on how to do it.

```
        Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://testurl.com/test/rest/example")
        req.Method = "GET"
        req.Headers("Authorization") = "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user:password"))
        Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

That's the only thing I have done so far, and the Authentication is working, but how do I post a file, using that BasicAuth Connection?

In the documentation they described posting a file like the following:

```
POST https://testurl.com/test/rest/abc/User/24/docs
 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
 
Form:
 
  file: Data
```

I would be thankfully, if someone could explain it to me, or even give an example.

Thank you and have a great day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981354/how-to-post-a-file-via-http-post-in-vb-net

Comment: @KęstutisRamulionis Thanks, but that doesnt require a BasicAuth and is just a direct upload. How is it possible to BasicAuth before?